# How to get an id from a div tag at the loading of the page and set it active?

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

I'm making a book-like pagination for my website. I simply paste a formatted text on the .html page with  tag to indicate which part belongs to which page.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showPages(id) {


    var totalNumberOfPages = 6;
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalNumberOfPages; i++) {

      if (document.getElementById('page' + i)) {

        document.getElementById('page' + i).style.display = 'none';
      }

    }
    if (document.getElementById('page' + id)) {

      document.getElementById('page' + id).style.display = 'block';
    }
  };
</script>

<div id="page1">
  <p>blah blah</p>
</div>
<div id="page2">
  <p>blah blah on a second page</p>
</div>
<div id="page3">
  <p>blah blah on a third page</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
      <a href="#" onclick="showPages('1')">1</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="showPages('2')">2</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="showPages('3')">3</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on a link from the pagination part, it shows exactly the right content.

The problem is, I can't show the first page when the webpage is loaded. It shows everything until you click to a link related to a page.

What should I add in the javascript part to render only the first page content when the page is loaded?

Comment: Are you looking for a JavaScript answer ? CSS would be best.

Comment: trigger your first anchor tag click on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function showPages(id=1){


    var totalNumberOfPages = 6;
    for(var i=1; i<=totalNumberOfPages; i++){

        if (document.getElementById('page'+i)) {

            document.getElementById('page'+i).style.display='none';
        }

    }
        if (document.getElementById('page'+id)) {

            document.getElementById('page'+id).style.display='block';
        }
};

showPages();
```

Try This. It should work on your machine.
https://jsfiddle.net/bog3L0em/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything in javascript, you can accomplish this by using CSS:

CSS classes:

```
.pageDisplayed{
    display:block;
}

.pageHidden{
   display:none;
}
```

Once these are available in your page via import of css file, change your HTML, the first page will have class pageDisplayed, so it will show on page load, the others will be hidden with class pageHidden:

```
<div class="pageDisplayed" id="page1"><p>blah blah</p></div>
<div class="pageHidden" id="page2"><p>blah blah on a second page</p></div>
<div class="pageHidden" id="page3"><p>blah blah on a third page</p></div>
```

Then modify your javascript function:

```
function showPages(id){


var totalNumberOfPages = 6;
for(var i=1; i<=totalNumberOfPages; i++){

    if (document.getElementById('page'+i)) {

        //document.getElementById('page'+i).style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('page'+i).classList.remove('pageDisplayed');
        document.getElementById('page' + i).classList.add('pageHidden');
    }

}
    if (document.getElementById('page'+id)) {

        //document.getElementById('page'+id).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('page'+id).classList.remove('pageHidden');
        document.getElementById('page' + id).classList.add("pageDisplayed");
    }
};
```

Comment: This is a working solution. Although, since I'm using an autohotkey to automatically convert a lot of texts to html format, it is complicated for me. Though it is a working solution, for anyone who would read it. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

To do this using javascript just add below line of code on window load function

```
document.querySelector("a").click();
```